# How to force pagination to page one when filters are used?

Tags: php

I have a page that displays records from a MySQL database in a table. On this page is multiple filters users can click to show desired results.  I have recently added pagination which works fine.

When the page is first loaded it will display all the results.  Right now it displays 9 results.  For testing purposes I am only allowing 6 results per page.  My problem is lets say a user first loads the page and then clicks on page 2 of pagination.  While on page two they decide to add a filter.  I have my filters set up with php if statements to change the query.  If they click on the first option that only should allow 2 results, which is does, but it doesn't automatically take me back to page 1 to show just those results.  It just stays on page 2 and the user would have to click on page 1 to get the proper results.

How do I change my pagination script to go to page 1 if a filter is clicked?

```
// Pagination Function
function pagination($query,$per_page=6,$page=1,$url='?'){   
global $conDB; 
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conDB,$query));
$total = $row['num'];
$adjacents = "2"; 

$prevlabel = "&lsaquo; Prev";
$nextlabel = "Next &rsaquo;";
$lastlabel = "Last &rsaquo;&rsaquo;";

$page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

$prev = $page - 1;                          
$next = $page + 1;

$lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);

$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1; // //last page minus 1

$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1){   
    $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $pagination .= "<li class='page_info'>Page {$page} of {$lastpage}</li>";

        if ($page > 1) $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$prev}'>{$prevlabel}</a></li>";

    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)){   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++){
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}</a></li>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                    
        }

    } elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)){

        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)) {

            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++){
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}</a></li>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                    
            }
            $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lpm1}'>{$lpm1}</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lastpage}'>{$lastpage}</a></li>";  

        } elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2)) {

            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++) {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}</a></li>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                    
            }
            $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lpm1}'>{$lpm1}</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lastpage}'>{$lastpage}</a></li>";      

        } else {

            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}</a></li>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                    
            }
        }
    }

        if ($page < $counter - 1) {
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$next}'>{$nextlabel}</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>{$lastlabel}</a></li>";
        }

    $pagination.= "</ul>";        
   }

   return $pagination;
}
?>
```

```
<?php
$page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
if ($page <= 0) $page = 1;

$per_page = 6; // Set how many records do you want to display per page.

$startpoint = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;


$statement = "`vendor_ads` WHERE `showingads` = 'yes' AND `admin` = 'enabled' AND `vendortype` = 'venue' AND (" . $str . ") ORDER BY cpc DESC"; // Change `records` according to your table name.


 $results = mysqli_query($conDB,"SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}");

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) != 0) {

// displaying records.
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
   echo "<table class='tablebox' width='1000' border='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr><td><a href='post_click.php?url=".$row["url"]."&username=".$row["username"]."&id=".$row["id"]."&cpc=".$row["cpc"]."'> <img src='".$row["imageurl"]."'></a>

    <a href='favorite_upload_script.php?favoriteid=".$row["favorite_id"]."&vendorname=".$row["vendorname"]."&imageurl=".$row["imageurl"]."&urlmainpage=".$row["url"]."&redirecturl=http://www.mybudgetbride.com/ad-display-template.php'><img src='/images/favorite_button.jpg' /></a>
    </td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><center><strong>".$row["vendorname"]."</strong></center></td>
    </tr>
    </table>";

   }
} 

else {

$statement = "`vendor_ads` WHERE `showingads` = 'yes'  AND `admin` = 'enabled' AND `vendortype` = 'venue' ORDER BY cpc DESC"; // Change `records` according to your table name.

$results = mysqli_query($conDB,"SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}");

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) != 0) {

// displaying records.
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
   echo "<table class='tablebox' width='1000' border='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr><td><a href='post_click.php?url=".$row["url"]."&username=".$row["username"]."&id=".$row["id"]."&cpc=".$row["cpc"]."'> <img src='".$row["imageurl"]."'></a>

    <a href='favorite_upload_script.php?favoriteid=".$row["favorite_id"]."&vendorname=".$row["vendorname"]."&imageurl=".$row["imageurl"]."&urlmainpage=".$row["url"]."&redirecturl=http://www.mybudgetbride.com/ad-display-template.php'><img src='/images/favorite_button.jpg' /></a>
    </td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><center><strong>".$row["vendorname"]."</strong></center></td>
    </tr>
    </table>";
  }
}
}

 ?>
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td><?php echo pagination($statement,$per_page,$page,$url='?');?></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div><!-- .wrap -->
```

Comment: "if a filter is clicked": what does that mean?

Comment: @developerwjk  I have about 15 checkboxes that can filter the results.  So for example some filter options are 2k and under, 2k to 4k, 4k and up.  When checked it goes into a string and into my query to change the results that are displayed.  Only, if a user is already on page 2 of pagination for initial results (all results) they will have to manually click back to page one of pagination in order to see the correct "filtered" results.

Comment: You can fix this by redesigning it to use ajax somehow...in other words, instead of the links actually going to a new page, they do an ajax call to pull down the contents of the next page and stick it in a div.  So the links refresh the data without ever leaving the page. Then the filter stuff will just do the same, refresh the data with an ajax call.